# Make a JSON file with multiple same format using PHP

Tags: php, json

Fist of all i would like to tell I am a beginner for JSON. I would like to know how to make a following format JSON using PHP. I think I want to use loop function.

Example:

```
[ { "id" : "1", "name" : "test1" },
  { "id" : "2", "name" : "test2" },
  { "id" : "3", "name" : "test3" },
  { "id" : "4", "name" : "test4" },
  { "id" : "5", "name" : "test5" } ]
```

In my PHP file have `$VALUE` variable in different places. I want know id and name values store method to make this JSON. I can not use $VALUE1, $VALUE2 etc.

Some places have following $VALUE variable with some data. is it method right to make this JSON

```
$VALUE = array("id" => "1", "name" => "test1");

$VALUE = array("id" => "3", "name" => "test3");
```

Comment: use array for value, `$VALUE = []; $VALUE[] = ["id" => "1", "name" => "test1"]; $VALUE[] = ["id" => "3", "name" => "test3"];`. Then `json_encode($VALUE);` will do what you need

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this if you wanted : using **arrays** and with **cast to an object**

```
 $json_php_oupout = [
                        (object)["id"=>"1", "name"=>"test1"], 
                        (object)["id"=>"2", "name"=>"test2"],
                        (object)["id"=>"3", "name"=>"test3"],
                        (object)["id"=>"4", "name"=>"test4"],
                        (object)["id"=>"5", "name"=>"test5"]
                    ];

  var_dump($json_php_oupout);
```

if you want VALUE as an array to it like this adding manually indexes or with a loops.

```
$VALUE[0] = (object)array("id" => "1", "name" => "test1");

$VALUE[1] = (object)array("id" => "3", "name" => "test3");
```

Comment: How to make it using $VALUE array

Answer (score 0):

I think that `json_encode()` and `json_decode()` will help you.

```
$array = [
  ["id" => 1, "name" => "test1"],
  ["id" => 2, "name" => "test2"],
  ["id" => 3, "name" => "test3"],
  ["id" => 4, "name" => "test4"]
];
$jsonEncoded = json_encode($array);
$jsonDecoded = json_decode($jsonEncoded);
var_dump("Json Encoded array to string:", $jsonEncoded);
var_dump("Json Decoded string to array:", $jsonDecoded);
```

> In order to update (add/update or remove) the encoded json array you need to decode first and encode again. There is no other way to add an "object" to an already encoded json string.

You can always check the official documentation for more information.
[json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)
[json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)